# How do I add a conditional constraint in smithy?

Tags: constraints, traits

```
struct Car {
    @required
    CarName: String

    BMWSerialNumber: String
}
```

In above example, how could I enforce BMWSerialNumber to be required, only if CarName == "BMW"?

I tried to add selector but it seems only work for the shape.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using smithy and java